# How to generate nunit TestResults.xml in visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, nunit

I am using nUnit with C# and Selenium in VS2013 to run my automated qa tests. I have added nunit references through Manage NuGet Packages, but can't figure out where is the testresults.xml or how to generate one after running nunit tests in the Test Explorer.

Comment: I think I have to use Nunit Console Runner. Any links/guide for setting it up is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Using Test Explorer and the NUnit or NUnit 3 adapter, there is no way to save the test results as an XML file. You would, as you say, have to install the NUnit console runner and run tests with it. You can use the NuGet NUnit.Runners package to get a copy of NUnit3-console runner into your project.